# GetData include sometime is Null

Tags: c#

I get data from my database with this code

```
var table = kantarDataSetTartimlarTableAdapter.GetData().Select(s =>  new
                    {
                        s.DateColumn,
                        s.Index
                    }).AsEnumerable().Select ((s, column) => new
                                          {                                                  
                                              s.DateColumn,                                                  
                                              s.Index                                                  
                                              column_no = column + 1
                                          });
```

If `date column` is not `null` I haven't got any problem. But when `date column` have `null` data I have a problem:

```
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
public System.DateTime event_start_date {
get {
    try {
        return ((global::System.DateTime)(this[this.tableDataTable1.event_start_dateColumn]));
    }
    catch (global::System.InvalidCastException e) {
        throw new global::System.Data.StrongTypingException("The value for column \'event_start_date\' in table \'DataTable1\' is DBNull.", e);
    }
}
set {
    this[this.tableDataTable1.event_start_dateColumn] = value;
}
```

}

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 1):

It appears your DB column & entity model are out of sync. If you are getting a `null` value back from the database then that field must be *nullable*. For that to map across to your model it must also support nullable dates.

You need to update `event_start_date` in your model to use `Nullable<DateTime>`/`DateTime?`.

Answer (score 0):

You may try providing a default value when reading the value from your database to ensure you aren't storing any nulls:

```
DateColumn = s.DateColumn ?? DateTime.MinValue
```

Answer (score 0):

I update `event_start_date` and I solve my problem

```
get {
                try {
                    if (this[this.table.DateTimeColumn] is DBNull)
                    {
                        return Convert.ToDateTime(null);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return ((global::System.DateTime)(this[this.table.DateTimeColumn]));
                    }
                }
                catch (global::System.InvalidCastException e) { 
                    throw new global::System.Data.StrongTypingException("Description", e);                        
                }
            }

            set {
                this[this.table.DateTimeColumn] = value;
            }
```